# Rationale behind construction of measure theory from semirings

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, self-learning, lebesgue-measure

I am studying a book (Aliprantis & Burkinshaw, "Principles of Real Analysis") that, in order to introduce the concept of measure, starts from semiring. In particular the authors state that:

> *"A semiring of sets is the simplest family of sets for which a measure theory can be built. It turns out that most 'reasonable' collection of sets satisfy the semiring properties" [p.94]*

I have the following two questions related to the issue:

1. *What do we gain from basing a construction of measure theory on semirings? Is there a pedagogical reason?*
2. *What are those "reasonable" collection of sets the authors most probably refer to that satisfy semiring properties, i.e. where do we actually find them elsewhere?*

Clearly, I cannot really foresee all the nuances related to those questions, hence it would be really nice to actually *see* what happens by opting for such a construction, and why in general semirings are a good starting point/option to talk about measures.

As always, any feedback is most welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The only time that I've seen that I actually wanted to use the Caratheodory construction starting from a semiring is in constructing the product measure, where the collection of products of pairs of measurable sets turns out to form a semiring. All other examples I can think of started with either an algebra (for example, the open and closed sets of a topological space) or a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Ian: First of all, thanks a lot for the comment to this question that apparently is not particularly interesting. Thus, trying to extract the most out of it... 1) Hence, historically, did Caratheodory started from a semiring? 2) Do you have an idea of what the authors refer to when they mentioned those "reasonable" collection of sets?

Comment: I do not think the theory began with semirings, historically. As for the latter point, I think the point is basically that requiring your "initially measurable sets" to be a semiring is the weakest requirement you can enforce. Unfortunately, because the definition is rather technical, in a sense I do not think it is the "simplest" definition.

Answer (score 0):

A nice example of a semiring is the class of half-open intervals $[a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$.  The ring generated by this class is the class of disjoint unions of half-open intervals.  The $\sigma$-ring generated by this class is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  It is marginally easier to initially define your measure on the semiring, before extending it further to the ring, and then the $\sigma$-ring.

A slightly more interesting example of a semiring is the class of products of half-open intervals $\Pi_{i=1}^n[a_i,b-i)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.