# Why not build Measure Theory with Algebras, instead of Semirings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

So, a semiring (SR) is a set $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\emptyset\in\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{S}$ is closed under finite complementation and intersection. An Algebra is a set $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ that does all that plus it's closed under finite unions. Most authors I know build Measure Theory(MT) from SRs, when they could totally build it up from $\mathcal{A}$ (at least, it's looking like that for a newbie). Are there any consequences for choosing one way over the other? I know starting from SRs and then migrating to $\sigma-$algebras makes the construction easier and more natural than if we stayed on with SRs. Does something similar happen if you start with semirings instead of $\mathcal{A}?$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "most authors build measure theory out of semirings", can you give some examples?  Most of the texts with which I am familiar build measure theory out of sigma-algebras, which are closed under complements and *countable* intersections and unions.  Of the top of my head, I can't even think of a book on measure theory which starts with algebras (rather than sigma-algebras).

Comment: [Achim Klenke](https://www.yumpu.com/de/document/read/8533897/klenke-wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie) also uses Semirings.  As far as I remember, it's easier to check that something (e.g. half-open quads in $\mathbf{R}^n$) is a semiring, and then proceed to construct an algebra from it.

Comment: I should've written "most authors I know", i'll fix that. They're brazilians, so I don't know if you'll be familiar with them: Introdução à medida e Integração, from Carlos Isnard, and Curso de Medida e Integração from Augusto Armando de Castro Jr both do that, they start from semirings and then move on to $\sigma-$algebras. I know one that starts from algebras of sets, and that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Additionally to the first two references, as said [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433770/rationale-behind-construction-of-measure-theory-from-semirings), in a similar question,[Principles of Real Analysis by Aliprantis & Burkinshaw](https://huynhcam.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/aliprantis_c-d-principles_of_real_analysis_third_edition-academic_press1998.pdf) start MT from SRs.

Comment: Essentially, your question boils down to "Why do some authors [a thing] one way, while other authors do it another?"  This seems like a question which depends very much on reading the authors' minds, which is out of scope here.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I can see it going that way, but I'm more concerned with the consequences of pursuing one way instead of the other. That, I believe, can be answered w/o trying to read the mind of the author in question. But I still don't have much of clue of which these consequences would be.

Comment: @GustavoDeSouza Then I would suggest that you edit your question in order to make the core mathematical question clearer.  Right now, one of the questions embedded in your post is "Is there any reason for that preference?", which requires mind reading.

Comment: That being said, I will also express my opinion that it doesn't really matter, and is, essentially, up to the preferences of the lecturer or author.  I would *guess* that the semiring model builds more naturally from topology (where there is an asymmetry between intersections and unions), but that is only a guess.  Like I said, the approach I know is to just jump right in and start with sigma-algebras.

Comment: Fair enough point, just edited that part out.

Comment: The books you mention introduce measure in semi-rings but they quickly move to sigma-algebra.  Why they introduce measure in semi-rings ? Because one of the simplest examples is a semi-ring: The semi-ring of finite length intervals in $\Bbb R$. 

A few older books, like Halmos, develops Measure Theory using semi-ring, ring and sigma-ring (instead of sigma-algebra).